# Need to Optimize javascript Code for website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi every one recently i build a site but there is a problem in some jquery function , some .src functions are not loaded completely in live website.

when i mouseover the image it take 4 to 5 seconds to change source of image .

here is my Code.....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".leads-padding img").click(function(){
        var oldSource = $(this).attr("src");
        if ( $(this).hasClass("clicked-image") ){
            $(this).attr("src", oldSource.replace("-1-1.jpg", ".jpg"));
            $(this).removeClass("clicked-image");
        }
        else{
            $(this).attr("src",oldSource.replace("-1.jpg","-1.jpg"));   
            $(this).addClass("clicked-image");
        }
    });
    $(".leads-padding img").mouseover(function(){
        if ( !$(this).hasClass("clicked-image") ){
            var oldSource = $(this).attr("src");
            $(this).attr("src",oldSource.replace(".jpg","-1.jpg"));
        }
    });
    $(".leads-padding img").mouseout(function(){
        if ( !$(this).hasClass("clicked-image") ){
            var oldSource = $(this).attr("src");
            $(this).attr("src", oldSource.replace("-1.jpg", ".jpg"));
        }
    });
```

`)};
)};`

here is HTML code .....

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leads-padding change-text" id="change-text6">
                <div class="margin-20">
                    <img src="../images/members/leads/waqas.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="img-leads6">
                </div>
                <div class="text-center leads">
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <p class="lead-designation">Des</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="leads-bio" id="txt6">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 bio">
                    <h1 class="color-orange">Name</h1>
                    <p>Des</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: you can just load the image and hide it then show it when on mouse hover

Comment: Remove the window.load call as you already have document load. You are both waiting for the page to finish loading then running your code after the page loads which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the entire image tag, I guess the optimum solution will be  if you can just **load all the images and then show/hide them based on your condition** (on `hover` and `click`).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".leads-padding img").click(function() {
      $(".img-2").toggle();
      $(".img-1").toggle();
    });
    $(".leads-padding img").hover(function() {
      $(".img-2").toggle();
      $(".img-1").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.img-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leads-padding change-text" id="change-text6">
                <div class="margin-20">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-1" id="img-leads6">
                    <img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg" class="img-responsive img-2" id="img-leads6">
                </div>
                <div class="text-center leads">
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <p class="lead-designation">Des</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="leads-bio" id="txt6">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 bio">
                    <h1 class="color-orange">Name</h1>
                    <p>Des</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can leave the `$(window).load` function and insert your functions directly in the `$(document).ready`.

Second, your images might take a while to appear if not cached, because they have to be loaded from the server. How large are they in size?

Comment: Probably shouldn't ask a question in an answer.

Comment: Correct, my bad. Could better be used in a comment.